# How Do I get theme colors of widgets in Qt6

Tags: colors, themes, qt6

I'm attempting to retrieve the theme colors of various widgets in Qt6. I've utilized QApplication.style(), but I'm uncertain as to how to obtain the colors I need from the QCommonStyle object that is returned. Specifically, I require the text color of a QLabel, the background color of a QListView, and so on. Currently, my approach involves creating temporary objects in order to retrieve the desired colors, but this is an inelegant workaround.

**Update:**

I've found the solution:

The colors are accessible through `QPalette`.

```
if option.state & QStyle.State_Active:
    if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
        textColor = QPalette.HighlightedText
        brightTextColor = QPalette.HighlightedText
    else:
        textColor = QPalette.WindowText
        brightTextColor = QPalette.BrightText
else:
    textColor = QPalette.WindowText
    brightTextColor = QPalette.BrightText
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution myself. You can find it above in the Update.